# Is it possible to PASTE image into Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

It is possible to include images in Jupyter notebook with various markup.

But is it possible to AUTOMATE this? I.e. I have image in clipboard, then I just press `Ctrl-V` and Jupyter server automatically takes this image, creates file in appropriate place and inserts markup for it.

I saw such things in Stackoverflow and JIRA.

Answer (score 18):

Yes.

1. Click the preferred cell that you want to paste the image into
2. Enter markdown mode by pressing `Esc` then `M`
3. Paste using `Ctrl` + `V`

Note: As @lextoumbourou suggested, ensure your notebook is up to date. I am using version *7.13.0*. I checked version using `conda list ipython`

Comment: works perfectly thanks, surprisingly: local laptop clipboard (w/ snipping-tool on a win10) transferred to a remote Ubuntu 20.x's jupyter notebook markdown cell (on chromium) via teamviewer w/o issue, +1 & bookmarked TQ.

Comment: **CAREFUL**: if you try and paste two different images in the same markdown cell the second pasted image will delete the first one, in my case:

naïvely I just pasted one image > ran the markdown cell > copied another > ran the markdown cell > the second image duplicated (first one dissapeared)

Answer (score 16):

Juypter Notebook now supports this natively as of [version 5.0.0](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#release-5-0-0). You should be able to upgrade Jupyter using `pip`:

```
pip install notebook --upgrade
```

or `conda`:

```
conda upgrade notebook
```

then you can simply drag-and-drop images into cells or paste them from your clipboard.

Comment: Images pasted directly in a markdown cell are ignored if you try to File->Save and export notebook as..->Markdown.  <p>

The pasted images are base64 encoded in the .ipynb file, & referred to in the .md file as `![image.png](attachment:5e81266f-de1a-4646-a45b-ce7efb2b90a8.png)`.  Of course, there is no such file by the name `5e81266f-de1a-4646-a45b-ce7efb2b90a8.png` in the zip file for the .md, so one is stuck. <p>
You need the image files if you are using mkdocs (or similar tool). <p>

Does anyone know of a way to extract these copy-pasted images as files? <p>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Its simple, navigate to Markdown and simply drag and drop your image and hit enter

Comment: This approach works

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can copy paste images in jupyter notebook.

Just go in notebook cell and select heading and paste the image.

That's it: now run the cell, the image will appear there.

Comment: just wondered to which path the image file is uploaded. It turns out it is stored base64 encoded in the cell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703463/where-are-copy-pasted-images-stored-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it using jupyter-notebook : 6.0.2

copy the image and paste directly into jupyter notebook as

'''
! [image.png] (attachment:image.png)
'''

Comment: can you explain further?  you have typed commands, what does that have to do with drag and drop?