# Where are copy-pasted images stored in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: image, jupyter-notebook

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598559/local-images-in-jupyter-notebook) but it hasn't been answered.

I launched a Jupyter server from PyCharm. I created a screenshot, and copy and pasted it into a Jupyter Notebook. The image wasn't otherwise saved. In Jupyter Notebook, the image appears like this: `![image.png](attachment:image.png)` and I can see the image on the Jupyter server, but I can't see the image in the notebook file in PyCharm. I can't find where the `image.png` file is stored. I looked through the folder that the notebook is in, and I used the file explorer to check if the image is anywhere on my computer.

Does Jupyter Notebook store the copy-pasted image as a file? and if yes, where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694656/8508004) fills in some information on what is going on.
When you pasted it into the markdown cell, it got encoded as an attachment in base64 in the cell information for that cell.
If you view the underlying code for the notebook in a text editor you should see encoded data. (You may wish to make a test notebook, separate from the one you care about, and add an image to test that after you save the edited new notebook.)

And so **there is no separate saved file**.

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the html element with browser debugger tool, you can see something like:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...FTkSuQmCC" alt="image.png">
```

Right clicking on the element in the debugger provides `Open Link a New Tab` allowing you to copy the image to other notebooks.